# Css radio buttons problem - How to style each radio button?

Tags: html, css

How to style each radio button?

I have tried this:

```
div.radio-toolbar {width:410px;}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;
    font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666666;
    width:106px;
    padding-left:4px;
}

.radio-toolbar #radio1 [type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio1.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
.radio-toolbar #radio2 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio2.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
.radio-toolbar #radio3 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio3.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">

    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
    <label for="radio1">Radio1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="false">
    <label for="radio2">Radio2</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
    <label for="radio3">Radio3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is more than css, but css-only is possible

origin code problem:

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Your control is **no longer visible** and **not clickable** to user - that means, **`:checked` never occur**.

To hide the default radio button, most people will use `opacity` (`visibility` should work but no one give it a try)

The solution will be

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
    opacity:0;
}
```

And for the label

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] + label{
    marign-left:-20px; /* change this 20px to default radio button size */
    padding-left:20px; /* change this to your background size to cover default radio */
}
```

The only problem for this solution: it limit your replacement image size, which needs to  close to origin radio button. If you need bigger control, you need javascript to trigger the radio button `.checked` porperty

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    .radio1 [type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio1.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
.radio2 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio2.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
.radio3 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url("../images/radio3.png") no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

then in HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" class="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
    <label for="radio1">Radio1</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Male  

      

    Female

input[type=radio] {

```
display: none;
```

}

label {

```
display: inline-block;  

cursor: pointer;  

position: relative;  

padding-left: 25px;  

margin-right: 15px;  

font-size: 13px;
```

}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {

```
content: "\2022";  

color: #f3f3f3;  

font-size: 30px;  

text-align: center;  

line-height: 18px;
```

}

label:before {

```
content: "";  

display: inline-block;  



width: 16px;  

height: 16px;  



margin-right: 10px;  

position: absolute;  

left: 0;  

bottombottom: 1px;  

background-color: #aaa;  

box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255,
```

255, .8);

}

.radio label:before {

```
border-radius: 8px;
```

}

Comment: I think you should fix the code formatting. But looks good otherwise

Comment: its all because i have pasted it directly cutting it from from my notepad that's yyy