# Radio button background only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

What I need to do is to replace the look of the radio button with image. That can be easily achieved with jQuery, but it this case I need to do it with CSS only. Is there any way to do that? Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="radio-buttons">
    <div class="holder">
        <span></span>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="cheetah" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <span></span>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="horse" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <span></span>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="lion" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to apply a style `background-image:` on the radio button, but of course it didn't work. Then I added the `<span>`'s and I am wonderig if I can set style to the buttons `display: none` , and somehow on `input:checked` to display the `<span>` which will be styled with `background-image:` ? Is this the right way or I am on completely wrong direction? And can it be achieved with CSS only at all ?

Edit: the radio buttons might be changed to checkboxes if needed.

Comment: A simple search for "style radio button with css" gave me this: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/

Comment: @DominikG _What I need to do is to replace the look of the radio button with image._ Your link doesn't include images. I would suggest you to use JQuery due the **cross browser compatibility**.

Comment: I don't need jQuery. And I don't need compatability as well.

Comment: It works the way described on the page, just use a background-image for the labels. And as described on the page: _This version of the code works in the latest version of all browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera and Chrome), so you don’t have to worry about whether or not it will work._

Comment: @ПанайотТолев [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080921/css-radio-buttons-problem-how-to-style-each-radio-button).

Comment: I have done something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081003/295852 and it worked well in browsers that supported it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dominik said that is almost the way to achieve this. May be his code is for a specific case, and I found something similar but much simple than that. I had to make list of photos, and on click of a photo, it must display the clicked photo, but larger and in section after the list. That's why it didn't work with me. But I will first explain everything and then I will paste my code.

The Dominic code will work only if the `label` is **next to** the `radio-button`. It didn't work for me because I have my `<label>`'s separated from the `radio-buttons`. Labels are in `<ul>` and the radio-buttons are in `<div>` after the `<ul>`. That way it doesn't work and that's why I needed to add another same `<label>` next to each `radio-button`. Now I had two labels for 1 radio button. So here is my entire code. I had styled the ul labels inline just to save some space in the css. I made it with bg-color so if someone want to try ... it works fine with bg-image too

HTML:

```
<div class="shell">
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li><label class="label" for="cheetah" style="background-color: white"></label></li>
            <li><label class="label" for="horse" style="background-color: yellow"></label></li>
            <li><label class="label" for="lion" style="background-color: green"></label></li>
            <li><label class="label" for="squirrel" style="background-color: red"></label></li>
            <li><label class="label" for="tiger" style="background-color: purple"></label></li>
            <li><label class="label" for="bear" style="background-color: black"></label></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="radio-buttons">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="cheetah" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="cheetah" ></label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="horse" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="horse" ></label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="lion" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="lion" ></label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="squirrel" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="squirrel"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="tiger" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="tiger"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="bear" value="" />
                <label class="label" for="bear" ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.shell { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }

ul { height: 150px; list-style: none; padding-bottom: 50px;  }

ul li {
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin-right: 14px; 
} 
ul li label {
    display: block; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul label {
    display: inline;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label.label {
    border: 1px  solid red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="cheetah"] {
    background-color: white
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="horse"] {
    background-color: yellow
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="lion"] {
    background-color: green
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="squirrel"] {
    background-color: blue
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="tiger"] {
    background-color: purple
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="bear"] {
    background-color: black
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Link I provided in the comment, you can use the following html:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-2-1" name="radio-2-set" class="regular-radio big-radio" /><label for="radio-2-1"></label><br />
<input type="radio" id="radio-2-2" name="radio-2-set" class="regular-radio big-radio" /><label for="radio-2-2"></label><br />
```

together with the css similar to:

```
.regular-radio {
display: none;
}

.regular-radio + label {
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-image: url("unchecked.png");
padding: 9px;
border-radius: 50px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.regular-radio:checked + label:after {
content: ' ';
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border-radius: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
background-image: url("checked.png");
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
text-shadow: 0px;
left: 3px;
font-size: 32px;
}

.regular-radio:checked + label {
background-image: url("checked.png");
border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be worked in this direction. I have posted the solution I got with the changes and for my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:

```
They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
The begin and end tags of the outermost block element must not be indented.
Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.
```